# Python - Destroying a StaticBoxSizer in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm trying to build an application in Python using wxpython library.

I would like to add and remove widgets dinamically like in the picture
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNB3q.png) so that i can add and remove how many StaticBoxSizer I want.

I got a good result in adding widgets while I can't get the way to remove the widgets. I'm successfull in destroying every widget in the StaticBoxSizer but I'm not able to destroy the container StaticBoxSizer itself: if I try to add many blocks and then removing one of them, in the onRemoveMaster method something happens and Python crash.

My code:

```
import wx 
import wx.xrc
import wx.aui
class Example(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
        size = wx.Size( 726,624 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

    self.InitUI()
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

def InitUI(self):

    self.number_of_added = 0

    self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

    #Setup MenuBar
    self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
    self.m_menu1 = wx.Menu()
    self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu1, u"MyMenu" )

    self.m_menu2 = wx.Menu()
    self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu2, u"MyMenu" )

    self.SetMenuBar( self.m_menubar1 )


    #Setup Main Container
    MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    self.ScrolledWindow = wx.ScrolledWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
    self.ScrolledWindow.SetScrollRate( 1, 1 )
    MainVerticalSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self.ScrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE )

    #Costruzione Master Sequence Tab
    self.MasterSequenceTab = wx.ScrolledWindow( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
    self.MasterSequenceTab.SetScrollRate( 1, 1 )
    self.MasterVSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    MasterButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

    self.ButtonAdd = wx.Button( self.MasterSequenceTab, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterButtonSizer.Add( self.ButtonAdd, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self.ButtonAdd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAddMaster)

    self.ButtonRemove = wx.Button( self.MasterSequenceTab, wx.ID_ANY, u"Remove", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterButtonSizer.Add( self.ButtonRemove, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self.ButtonRemove.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onRemoveMaster)

    self.MasterVSizer.Add( MasterButtonSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL, 5 )     

    self.onAddMaster(self)
    self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.MasterSequenceTab, u"Master Sequence", False )


    #Finalizzazione finestre
    MainVerticalSizer.Add( self.m_auinotebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

    self.ScrolledWindow.SetSizer( MainVerticalSizer )
    self.ScrolledWindow.Layout()
    MainVerticalSizer.Fit( self.ScrolledWindow )
    MainSizer.Add( self.ScrolledWindow, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.SetSizer( MainSizer )
    self.Layout()
    self.Centre( wx.BOTH )


def onAddMaster(self, event):

    self.number_of_added += 1

    self.MastersbSizerAdded = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self.MasterSequenceTab, 100+self.number_of_added, wx.EmptyString ),wx.VERTICAL )

    self.MasterCheckEnableAdded = wx.CheckBox( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 200+self.number_of_added, u"Enable", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterCheckEnableAdded.SetValue(True)
    self.MastersbSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterCheckEnableAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5 )

    MasterfgSizerAdded = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

    self.MasterTextNomeAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1000+self.number_of_added, u"Nome", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextNomeAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterTextNomeAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlNomeAdded = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 300+self.number_of_added, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 566,-1 ), 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterCtrlNomeAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterTextDescrizioneAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1100+self.number_of_added, u"Descrizione     ", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextDescrizioneAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterTextDescrizioneAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlDescrizione1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 400+self.number_of_added, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 566,-1 ), 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterCtrlDescrizione1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MastersbSizerAdded.Add( MasterfgSizerAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    MasterfgSizerAdded2 = wx.FlexGridSizer( 3, 6, 0, 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

    self.MasterTextSubjectAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1200+self.number_of_added, u"Subject Area", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextSubjectAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterTextSubjectAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlSubjectAdded = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 500+self.number_of_added, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterCtrlSubjectAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterTextAlimentanteAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1300+self.number_of_added, u"          Alimentante", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextAlimentanteAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterTextAlimentanteAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlAlimentanteAdded = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 600+self.number_of_added, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterCtrlAlimentanteAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterTextGroupAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1400+self.number_of_added, u"          Num group", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextGroupAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterTextGroupAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlGroupAdded = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 700+self.number_of_added, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterCtrlGroupAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterTextSchedulingAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1500+self.number_of_added, u"Schedulazione", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextSchedulingAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterTextSchedulingAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    MasterCtrlSchedulingChoicesAdded = [ u"G", u"S", u"D", u"Q", u"M", u"BM", u"TM", u"SM", u"A" ]
    self.MasterCtrlSchedulingAdded = wx.Choice( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 800+self.number_of_added, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, MasterCtrlSchedulingChoicesAdded, 0 )
    self.MasterCtrlSchedulingAdded.SetSelection( 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterCtrlSchedulingAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterTextValidoAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 1600+self.number_of_added, u"          Record valido", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextValidoAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterTextValidoAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    MasterCtrlValido1Choices = [ u"Y", u"N" ]
    self.MasterCtrlValidoAdded = wx.Choice( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 900+self.number_of_added, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, MasterCtrlValido1Choices, 0 )
    self.MasterCtrlValidoAdded.SetSelection( 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded2.Add( self.MasterCtrlValidoAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self.MastersbSizerAdded.Add( MasterfgSizerAdded2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self.MasterVSizer.Add( self.MastersbSizerAdded, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )       

    self.MasterSequenceTab.SetSizer( self.MasterVSizer )
    self.MasterSequenceTab.Layout()
    self.MasterVSizer.Fit( self.MasterSequenceTab )

def onRemoveMaster(self, event):    

    for i in range(16,0,-1):
        button = 100*i+self.number_of_added
        widget = self.MasterSequenceTab.FindWindowById(button)              
        widget.Destroy()            

    self.MasterSequenceTab.SetSizer( self.MasterVSizer )
    self.MasterSequenceTab.Layout()
    self.MasterVSizer.Fit( self.MasterSequenceTab )         

    self.number_of_added -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to create a new panel class with all those controls parented to it, and then just add and delete instances of the panel.
The panel instances could be stored in a list.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I added a panel containing the StaticBoxSizer and now it works.